# sql query with percent and aggregation functions

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, aggregate

I'm trying to write a sql query where I need number of scores > 3 by county, then for counties on that list I need to produce a percentage of rooms with scores < 3.  So I need three columns, County Name, # of scores > 3 by county, % of rooms with scores < 3 by county

```
    SELECT County = c.Description, [Score > 3] = count(s.Score),  
  ((select count(room.Name) where s.Score< 3) /( select count(room.Name) ) * 100)
    FROM Sites AS s
    inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
    inner join Counties as c on p.County_Id = c.Id
    inner join Rooms as room on s.Id = room.Site_Id
    where s.Score > 3
    Group By c.Description
```

Comment: And what problem are you having right now?

Comment: the problem is the query.  The third column, the percentage of rooms with scores < 3...can't figure that one out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicating the issue, rather than subselects you can just limit the data returned by using the `HAVING` clause, then use `CASE` in the `COUNT`:

```
SELECT  County = c.Description,
        [Score > 3] = COUNT(CASE WHEN Sites.Score > 3 THEN 1 END),
        [% Score < 3] = 100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN Sites.Score < 3 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(1)
FROM    Sites
        INNER JOIN Profiles
            ON Sites.Profile_Id = Profiles.Id
        INNER JOIN Counties 
            ON Profiles.County_Id = Counties.Id
        INNER JOIN Rooms 
            ON Sites.Id = Rooms.Site_Id
GROUP BY c.Description
HAVING  COUNT(CASE WHEN Sites.Score > 3 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

**[Demo on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7cc9f/2)**

**EDIT**

```
SELECT  County = c.Description,
        [Score > 3] = COUNT(CASE WHEN Sites.Score > 3 THEN 1 END),
        [% Score < 3] = 100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN Sites.Score < 3 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*),
        [Score > 3] = SUM(CASE WHEN Sites.Score > 3 THEN RoomCount ELSE 0 END),
        [% Score < 3] = 100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN Sites.Score < 3 THEN RoomCount ELSE 0 END) / SUM(RoomCount)
FROM    Sites
        INNER JOIN Profiles
            ON Sites.Profile_Id = Profiles.Id
        INNER JOIN Counties 
            ON Profiles.County_Id = Counties.Id
        INNER JOIN 
        (   SELECT Site_Id, RoomCount = COUNT(*)
            FROM   Rooms 
            GROUP BY Site_Id
        ) Rooms
            ON Sites.Id = Rooms.Site_Id
GROUP BY c.Description
HAVING  COUNT(CASE WHEN Sites.Score > 3 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: I think that's working, I have to double check the numbers....what does the 1 represent in COUNT(1) on the [% Score < 3 ] line?

Comment: If a site has multiple rooms, and whatever score a site has all of the rooms in that site get the same score, how do I get another column with % of rooms with a score < 3?

Comment: Using `COUNT(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`, I didn't even mean to do it. `COUNT(*)` is the same and clearer. With regard to the second bit, i am not sure exactly what you are asking, I think the answer I posted would give the output required. In case it doesn't I've added a second query that might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Score > 3] = count(s.Score) 

...

where s.Score > 3
```

Both statements are not needed. In fact your Where clause limits all operations to s.score >3, which is not ideal when you are also trying to pull data from scores <3.

If you are trying to count both the cases where s.Score>3 and where it is <3,  you need to use the CASE statement

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN s.score < 3 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS Hiscores,  
SUM(CASE WHEN s.score >    3 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) /count(s.scores) AS percentLowScores
```

This should do it

```
  SELECT c.Description County, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN s.score < 3 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS Hiscores,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN s.score > 3 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) /count(s.scores) AS percentLowScores

    FROM Sites AS s
    inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
    inner join Counties as c on p.County_Id = c.Id
    inner join Rooms as room on s.Id = room.Site_Id

    Group By c.Description
```

Comment: that is just naming the column, that is the second column which I do need.  I need three columns of data

Comment: is the third column producing null and zero?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cast`

```
SELECT County = c.Description, [Score > 3] = count(s.Score), 
    ( Cast(select count(room.Name) where s.Score < 3 ) as float / ( select count(room.Name) ) * 100)
    FROM Sites AS s
    inner join Profiles as p on s.Profile_Id = p.Id
    inner join Counties as c on p.County_Id = c.Id
    inner join Rooms as room on s.Id = room.Site_Id
    where s.Score > 3
    Group By c.Description
```